# Integration of Azure Devops and Python for passing test results from automation script and update in Azure Devops?

Tags: python, azure-devops, automation, appium

I'm currently performing some mobile app automation with Appium and Python, where test cases are on Azure Devops.

I have done the same thing with Appium, Python and TestLink. And I have passed the test results automatically to TestLink using TestLink-API-Python-client.

Is there anyway I could do the same thing with Azure Devops?

Comment: i was using xunit reports and test report upload task

Comment: @4c74356b41 - Can you elaborate a bit what and how you have done?

Comment: @AaliaSajana What's the result after trying 4c74356b41's solution? It is publish test result task of pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

this is the yaml code for the pipeline (excerpt) that I've been using for uploading tests of pytest to Azure Devops:

```
- script: PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) pytest python/tests --type test --junitxml=test_everything.xml
  displayName: "Run pytest"

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/test_*.xml'
    searchFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/deployment'
  condition: always()
```